# Does JavaFX support RTSP streaming?

Tags: javafx, rtsp

This is my code:

```
Media media = new Media("rtsp://192.168.1.206:554");
final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
MediaView view = new MediaView(player);
Group root = new Group();
root.getChildren().add(view);
primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
primaryStage.show();
player.play();
```

But there's an exception.

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 2):

`rtsp` is not supported till date. The supported protocols are :

- FILE
- HTTP
- JAR
- HLS

For more information go through [Media](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) official documentation.